# replacing '-' with np.nan converts the data type to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `df` as below :

```
 +------+----+
 |  x   |  y |
 +------+----+
 |ABCD  | -  |           
 |DEFG  | -  |
 +------+----+
```

with data types of `x` and `y` being object, after replacing the '-' with nan using the below

```
df = df.replace('-', np.NaN)
```

It converts the data type of column `y` as float while the data type of column `y` is expected to remain as object. Also when I try to find out the list of columns having NA values after replacing with NA values it doesn't show any columns having NA values whereas the column `y` has NA values. Why is the issue being caused?

EDIT : I'm able to find the columns having NA values as below

```
df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is only `NaN`s in columns convert column to floats. Possible solution is use [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) by original `dtype`s:

```
df = df.replace('-',np.NaN).astype(df.dtypes)

print (df.dtypes)
x    object
y    object
dtype: object

print (df.applymap(type))
               x                y
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
```

If want test columns with missing values then use:

```
print (df.columns[df.isna().any()])
Index(['y'], dtype='object')
```

Another similar idea is extract only NaNs columns and convert them to objects:

```
df = df.replace('-',np.NaN)


d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns[df.isna().all()], 'object')
print (d)
{'y': 'object'}

df = df.astype(d)

print (df.dtypes)
x    object
y    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Any other alternate solutions is present apart from the one which you wrote ?

Comment: @user3046211 - Can you explain your problem? Why cannot use it?

Comment: It worked, but I'm curious to know if there are alternative solutions present.

Comment: @user3046211 - Added another idea, I think better if need convert only few  (or one)c olumns to objects